# Characterization of $S^{-1}R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Let $R $ be a commutative ring and $S $ a multiplicative subset of  $R $.

Is any $S^{-1}R $-module of the form $S^{-1}M $ with $M $ an $R$-module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $S^{-1}R$-module $M$ can be regarded as an $R$-module via
$$
rx=\frac{r}{1}x
$$
(assuming $1\in S$, which is not restrictive). For better clarity, denote this $R$-module by $\check{M}$. Now, what's $S^{-1}\check{M}$?

Consider the map $f\colon M\to S^{-1}\check{M}$ defined by $f(x)=x/1$ and prove it is an isomorphism of $S^{-1}R$-modules.

Comment: But $S $ an arbitrary multiplicative set of $R$ is not necessarily it contains no divisors of zero. So $f$ in general is not injective.

Comment: @AskySaw Why? Note that $M$ is a module over $S^{-1}R$ to begin with. The canonical homomorphism $N\to S^{-1}N$ may not be injective if $N$ is an $R$-module. But when $M$ is as chosen in the answer, there is no problem: just verify it.